# spring mvc project not working from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I downloaded project from mkyong for learning spring mvc .
http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Spring3-MVC-HelloWorld-Example.zip

when I created war from command line using mvn clean install and deploy war it in tomcat webapp folder. It works fine. But when i import it in eclipse and run from there it gives me error 
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

tried everything.Search other similar question but no use.
Note: Rather than posting whole code i given link where project can be downloaded

Comment: Right click pom.xml and run maven clean, then maven install

Comment: If you have maven installed, go the path where pom.xml is located, convert dynamic project into maven project using following command
mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse. 
You can achieve same by using m2 plugin(Select project, right click on it select Configure-Convert to maven project)

Comment: ohh that was grt.Its working now , But every time I need to do that ?

Comment: How did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Inside Eclipse , find server.xml then, at the bottom of the file you should find this line as it is (if not juste replace the one you have by the following one)

```
<Context docBase="SpringMVC" path="/SpringMVC" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SpringMVC"/></Host>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have edited the code, that make the mapping name incorrect.
My advice is try to get the original version, than import it in eclipse. if you can directly do maven clean and maven install then just continue.
If can't, try to convert the dynamic project to maven project.
That's all.Good Luck.